# cascade multiple select in javascript

Tags: javascript

am having cascading parameter like country and city its work well...in list box so now i have to convert last level of cascade list box to multi-select  on load how to achieve?? this in javascript:

```
country:<select id="country">
<option selected="selected">--Select Country--</option>
</select>

city:<select id="city">
<option selected="selected">--Select City--</option>
</select>
```

city value have to load to this selection so it city single -listbox have to hide then only value to pass to this...multiselect::

```
  city multiple:<select multiple id="multiselect" style="width: 300px">

              </select>
```

[reference example](http://demos.9lessons.info/sections_demo.php)

Comment: I don't like your definition of "well". Try selecting "select country" from the first select.

Comment: did u refere this  link http://demos.9lessons.info/sections_demo.php

Comment: I'm saying that if you select a country you get a list of cities, but if you later select "select country" entry in the first widget you get a list of countries in the second widget (clearly nonsense).